# ANGULAR 5 : Casting any to object

Tags: angular, casting

I use Angular 5 I want to cast for an object of type any to object.

```
<select #selectedSupplier (change)="onSelectSupplier(selectedSupplier.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let supplier of suppliers" [value]="supplier">                                                                                                                                                
        {{ supplier.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

And at the type level when I try to display the results on the console with this function

```
// Result is [object Object]
onSelectSupplier(supplier){
    console.log(supplier);
}

// Result is undefined
onSelectSupplier(supplier){
    console.log(supplier.name);
}
```

So i want to cast supplier: any to my Object below

```
export class Supplier{
    name: string;

    constructor(name: string){
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

Comment: The types only exist at runtime, so this wouldn't solve your issue. Actually, the issue is using `[value]`, as this only handles strings. That is why it's being converted to `[object Object]` (which is actually a string). You should instead use `ngValue` for object

Comment: @user184994 Thank for your reply. can u explain how can i use ngValue ?

Comment: I've added an answer below, and a link to a StackBlitz demo that should show it working with `[ngValue]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types only exist at runtime, so this wouldn't solve your issue.

Actually, the issue is using `[value]`, as this only handles strings. That is why it's being converted to [object Object] (which is actually a string). You should instead use `ngValue` for object. I'd also recommend using `ngModel`, like so:

```
<select #selectedSupplier [(ngModel)]="selected" (change)="onSelectSupplier(selected)">
    <option *ngFor="let supplier of suppliers" [ngValue]="supplier">                                                                                                                                                
        {{ supplier.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

**[Here is a Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nj9qrd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**